# multiple user input prompts to ask user while submitting form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello everyone I need help .  I am making an product entry website, where the user enters product detail in a form and submits it.

While processing the form I want to pause execution and give a popup to the user for entering the stock of each product. After the user enters the product's stock, then the form will be submitted successfully. I attempted to use prompt but prompt can take only one user input.
note: multiple user input while execution pause.

```
constructor() {
 super();
 this.state={
  products:[],
  productName:'',
  category:'',
  subCategory:'',
  hsnCode:'',
  mrp:0,
  tax:0,
  purchasePrice:0,
  status:1,
  createdAt: new Date(),
      }
 }

handleSubmit(e){
         event.preventDefault();
        this.state.products.map(
  (product)=>{
        if (product.pid=="S") {
          let stock= prompt("enter your stock");
          let uom= prompt("enter your uom");
          console.log(stock);
          console.log(uom);
        }
   );

 }
```

REAL TIME EDIT: So i updated my question again with new code. I am making billing software where the user selects already entered products to make invoices.  Sometimes the user enters new products in billing panel when the product is not available in product master.

I am entering those products into product master, but the problem is the users only enter name,tax,price,quantity. I also want stock and units of that product. I want to give a prompt but prompt works only for one user input I need at least two inputs.

Editor note:  I'm making an assumption here, but the question is something along the lines of: "I have multiple variables that I want to require before submitting a form, what options do I have besides prompt to accomplish this?"

Comment: Your problem isn't very clear. So if they search for a specific item and there's more than 1 of that product, there's a popup asking them to specify the amount of that product they want?

Comment: where is the react part?, you can avoid using propmt altogether, and use some material-ui library component as popup component,

Comment: i updated my question look at it and i uploaded an image for better understanding . don't give me minus ranking i actually worked very hard in it

Answer (score 0):

Got two answers for you, neither of which display my "awesome reactjs skills".

Take multiple values in a single prompt, validate the input and split the string... which is some form of sidestepping the issue of using prompts.
Ex:

```
    while(true){
  // noprotect
    var i= prompt("Item not in database. Please enter your stock followed by uom, or cancel and check for typing errors. Two numbers, comma separated please.","0, 0");
    var a=i.split(','); 
    if(a.length==2 && Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(a[0])) && Number.isInteger(Number.parseInt(a[1]))){
        let stock=a[0];
        let uom=a[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

This might not be the best answer, as your user may not have stock or uom, which leads to false information being entered/confusion and panic.  It's also kinda ugly, and... well... // noprotect.  That fun thing.  Confused users might be left in prompt hell lest they cancel.

A better answer would be to approach the problem differently, break out of form submission and link your user to the right place to enter that information.  To be clear, this probably means creating an additional form for when this happens.

Lastly, it's worth noting that there's probably a syntax error in your code (in case you were fine with multiple prompts, and the code was just breaking).

```
handleSubmit(e){//<--this is a lonely '{'
         event.preventDefault();
        this.state.products.map(
  (product)=>{
        if (product.pid=="S") {
          let stock= prompt("enter your stock");
          let uom= prompt("enter your uom");
          console.log(stock);
          console.log(uom);
        }
   );//<--this is a lonely ')'. 

 }//<--this is closing the brace opened at (product)=>{ , which probably means that ')' should be a '}'.
```